# Facebook offline_access but access tokens still expire

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-php-sdk, access-token, facebook-oauth

I have written an application to manage a user's Facebook notifications. The app requests offline_access as well as manage notifications permissions. My logs have been filling up with Facebook errors. I understand that when a users changes their password the token is going to expire, but what I don't understand is why I am getting these errors:

```
Facebook Error: Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1320012000. The current unix time is 1320191317. 
Facebook Error: (#200) The "manage_notifications" permission is required in order to query the user's notifications.
```

They are occurring way too often to be users just rejecting the permissions and the access tokens that are expiring have expirations of 0.

Comment: When you get one of these errors, can you dump the access_token associated to your logs and then put it in http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and see if that explains anything?

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that useful tool.  On the ones that are expiring other than changing passwords, they have the typical 1 hour expiration and the scopes are only email.